# Blue screen error : stop code system_service_exception

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, bsod, reboot

Problems encountered on the PC with windows 10 21h1 :
i started the PC and after short period of time it restarted but had no signal to monitor;
after several attempts to restart it i received a blue screen error with the message stop code `system_service_exception`;  again no signal to monitor /
after several shut downs and switching off / on of the power supply the PC started with signal to monitor;

after that:

i searched the internet about this blue screen error and i understood that it is about updating the system and the drivers;
i checked the windows update and indeed there were several minor updates waiting for installation;
i checked with `chkdsk` and i didn't have any errors;
all my drivers are up to date;

My question is if i need to reinstall the operating system after this blue screen error so that i don't have any more problems ? (so far i haven't had such blue screen error due to updates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked the windows update and indeed there were several minor
> updates waiting for installation;

I would (just to be certain) check updates again, and driver updates again (especially Video). Now one final restart.

Then if running smoothly, I would not reinstall the OS.

But this is a good time to ensure you have good backups in case you should decide to reinstall later.